# Recursive function showing segmentation issue C++

Tags: c++, recursion

This code is for recursive function practice. When I run the code, it stops at the "POWER" cout line, then my compiler shows a segmentation error. The function that follows the POWER line is supposed to recursively raise number "a" to the power of number "b". I'm not sure how to fix this, can anyone help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

/**** Recursive backwards print, prints a string starting from last index to first*****/

void printReverse(string s, int i)
{
  if(i < s.size()) 
    {  
      printReverse(s.substr(1), i);
      cout<<s[i];
    }    
    else
    {   
      return;  
    }
  }
 


   /****   Recursive power function, computes a^b, where b can be positive or negative*****/
int recPower(double a, int b)
  {   
    int i = b; //i = b, so int a can be multiplied int b times
     
    if (i == 0) //base 
      return 1;

    else //multiply A by B, B times
     {
       a *= b;
       return recPower(a, b); //recursive
       i--; //decrement i until it equals 0
     }
  }


   
   /****   Recursive string replace, replaces all instances of a character in a string with another character*****/
string recReplace(string s2, int i, char old, char neW)
   { 
       if(s2[i] == old) //search for old char
      {
        i = neW; //replace it
        i++; //iterate i
       }
    recReplace(s2, i, old, neW); //call function
    return s2;
   }



/****   Recursive list find   > Searches if x exists in list, returns true if found, false otherwise*****/
int recListFind(vector<int> v, int i, int x)
  {
    if(v[i] == x)    
      {       
        cout << x << " exists in the vector."<<endl;  
        i++;
        recListFind(v, i, x);
      }    
      return true;
    }



int main()
  {     
    cout << "PRINT REVERSE" << endl;
    cout << "----------" << endl;    
    string s1 = "hello world";    
    cout << "String: " << s1 << endl;    
    cout << "Reversed: ";    
    printReverse(s1, 0);       
    cout << endl;   
     
     
     /* Computes a^b (power function) */    
    cout << "POWER" << endl;    
    cout << "----------" << endl;    
    int a = 2, b = -3;    
    cout << a << "^" << b << " = ";    
    cout << recPower(a, b) << endl;    
    cout << endl;    
   
   
    /* Replaces a character in a string with a new one */    
    cout << "REPLACE" << endl;    
    cout << "----------" << endl;    
    string s2 = "-h-e-l-l-o-";    
    char oldChar = '-';    
    char newChar = ' ';   
    cout << "String: " << s2 << endl;    
    cout << "> Replace '" << oldChar << "' with '" << newChar << endl;    
    recReplace(s2, 0, oldChar, newChar);    
    cout << "String: " <<  s2 << endl;    
    cout << endl;    
   
   
    /* Searches for value in vector */    
    cout << "FIND" << endl;    
    cout << "----------" << endl;    
    int x = 7;    
    cout << "Does " << x << " exist in the vector? ";    vector<int> v = {5, 1, 6, 7, 9};    
    cout << recListFind(v, 0, 7) <<  endl;    
    cout << endl;    
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is quite straight forward, you are doing the `recPower` function with `b`. In the function, if `b` is not 0, you call `recPower` with an unmodified value of `b` (whilst ever modifying `a`). This will always end up with infinite recursion which is going to overflow your stack.

A solution could be:

```
int recPower(double a, int b, int times) {        
  if (times == 0) 
    return a;

  else
    return b * recPower(a, b, --times); 
}

int recPower(double a, int b) {
    return recPower(a, b, b);
}
```

Even if you fix this, you have another problem. `b` can be negative, which based on your logic will continue to recurse while decrementing until it overflows and goes back to 0. You will cause this case with your first test case. You should think about the types that are allowed in this function, consider making them unsigned, or dealing explicitly with the negative `b` case.

Comment: Also for the `recReplace` function. From clang-cl: **warning : all paths through this function will call itself [-Winfinite-recursion]**

Comment: @AdrianMole Yeah, but the question is (or at least should be) only about the first one. I think the questions should remove the rest.